# How do I split up my routes using Express.Router() into multiple files?

Tags: node.js, express, express-router

I am trying to figure out how to split the routes in my routes.js file into multiple files. My current routes.js file looks like this:

```
const pullController = require('./controllers/pullController');
const userController = require('./controllers/userController');

const routes = require('express').Router();
routes.get('/openpullinfo', pullController.getOpenPullRequestInfo);
.
.
.
routes.post('/user', userController.createUser);

module.exports = routes;
```

I want to have a different routes file (i.e. `userRoutes.js`) for each controller because there are just too many routes in my single routes.js file and it's becoming unmanageable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a set of routes file (`userRoutes.js`, `pullRoutes.js`...). In these files, you can [use the express.Router class to create modular, mountable route handlers](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html). Then in the main file, you mount all your routers in your Express application.

##### Example :

- userRoutes.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res) {

    res.send('Get users controller');
});

router.post('/', function (req, res) {

    res.send('Post user controller');
});

module.exports = router;
```

- server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use(express.urlencoded())
app.use(express.json())


const userRoutes = require('./userRoutes');

app.use('/users', userRoutes);

app.listen(80);
```

In the browser, `http://localhost/users` gives me the text `Get users controller`

Comment: Can I further split userRoutes into multiple files? I have too many routes in the same router and the file is thousands of lines now. I want to further split the router into multiple lines.